# How to convert this SAS code to SQL Server code?

Tags: sql, sas

SAS CODE:

```
data table1;
set table2;
_sep1 = findc(policynum,'/&,'); 
_count1 = countc(policynum,'/&,');

_sep2 = findc(policynum,'-');   
_count2 = countc(policynum,'-');

_sep3 = findc(policynum,'_*');  
_count3 = countc(policynum,'_*');
```

How can I convert this into a select statement like below:

```
select 
    *,
    /*Code converted to SQL from above*/
from table2
```

For example I tried the below code:

```
select 
    *,
    charindex('/&,',policynum) as _sep1,                            
    LEN(policynum) - LEN(REPLACE(policynum,'/&,','')) as _count1

from table2
```

But I got a ERROR 42S02: Function 'CHARINDEX(UNKNOWN, VARCHAR)' does not exist. Unable to identify a function that satisfies that given argument types. You may need to add explicit typecasts.

Please note that the variable pol_no is: 'character varying(50) not null'.

I am running this on using Aginity Workbench for Netezza. I believe this is IBM.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; and (3) an explanation of the logic.  People do a better job explaining things than code.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site  Unfortunately code conversion is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please attempt to solve the problem and then ask questions related to that attempt. Thanks!

Comment: What SQL language are you using? The functions and operations differ across so you need to provide that. For context though,`FINDC`, simply finds those characters and `COUNTC` counts those characters. It returns the first location for either `/` or `&` so you may need to use two CHARINDEX functions instead of one and take the minimum between the two to find the earliest occurence. There may be a different function better suited, but we'd need to know your RDBMS to answer that.

Comment: I wrote in the title that I'm using SQL server. I'm running it in Aginity Workbench (Netezza).

Comment: What system? IBM, Oracle, Microsoft? That's what's being asked for here and it does matter. They're all SQL servers, just different varieties so that's not informative.

Comment: Can you explain why that code didn't work? Did it compile? (If not, what error did you get?) Did it run? (If not, what error did you get?) Did it blow up your pc. (If yes, do you have a video of it?)

Comment: Apologies for the lack of info, I added the error I got to my description. I also added that I'm running this in Microsoft. If more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Oracle based on CHARINDEX() this may work:
You need to apply it twice, once for each character and take the minimum to find the first occurrence. 
There may be a better suited function within Oracle, but I don't know enough to suggest one.

```
select 
    *,
    min(charindex('/',policynum), charindex('&', policynum)) as _sep1                            
    from table2
```

EDIT: based on OP notes.

Netezza seems like IBM which means use the INSTR function, not CHARINDEX.

```
select 
    *,
    min(instr(policynum, '/'), instr(policynum, '&')) as _sep1
 from table2
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2336.htm

Comment: I just ran this code and got an error saying 'charindex does not exist, unable to find a function that satisfies the given argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts'

Comment: I've edited this to reflect netezza but still not sure that's your database. If this doesn't work, you need to explicitly state the server type and version to ensure you get the correct functions.

Answer (score 0):

`FINDC` & `COUNTC` functions are basically used for searching a character & counting them.

You can use `LIKE` operator from SQL to find characters with '%' and '_' wildcards

e.g. -

`SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> LIKE '%-%';`

and

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> LIKE '%-%';`

You can use regular expressions in the `LIKE` operator as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't want to create a whole select statement for just the _sep1 field above individually, I want to include _sep1, _count1, etc. as fields that are part of another select statement. for example:

select *,
 charindex('/&,',pol_no) as _sep1,       
 LEN(pol_no) - LEN(REPLACE(pol_no,'/&,','')) as _count1

 from table

Comment: Your question didn't have these details.
And you can have subqueries or multiple column selects in the SQL query as per your needs.